C/C++socket construction HTTPS gzip request, response message 'inflate ERROR: ZDATA_RROR' during decompression process
C/C++socket construction HTTPS gzip request, response message 'inflate ERROR: ZDATA_RROR' during decompression process
why The message returned by  the server is abnormal, and some websites request to add "Accept-Encoding: gzip" to the message, but the returned result cannot be correctly decompressed. Could you please help me take a look, experts
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define BUFFER 500000

int decompress_string(const char* input, uLong input_length, char* output, uLong *output_length) {
    printf("input_length=%d\n",input_length);
    z_stream stream={0};
    stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    stream.opaque = Z_NULL;

    if (inflateInit2(&stream,15 + 32) != Z_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: inflateInit call error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    stream.next_in = (Bytef*)input;
    stream.avail_in = input_length;
    stream.next_out = (Bytef*)output;
    stream.avail_out = *output_length;

    int ret = Z_OK;
    while (stream.avail_in != 0 && ret == Z_OK) {
        ret = inflate(&stream, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
        if (ret == Z_STREAM_END) {
            break;
        } else if (ret != Z_OK) {
            if (ret == Z_DATA_ERROR) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Z_DATA_ERROR while decompressing data\n");
            } else if (ret == Z_MEM_ERROR) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Z_MEM_ERROR while decompressing data\n");
            }
            if (inflateEnd(&stream) != Z_OK) {
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: inflateEnd call error\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
            
        if (stream.avail_out == 0) {
            printf("stream.avail_out\n");
            stream.next_out = (Bytef*)(output + stream.total_out);
            stream.avail_out = *output_length - strlen(output);
        }
    }
 

    *output_length = strlen(output);

    if (inflateEnd(&stream) != Z_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: inflateEnd call error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}


int main() {

    int sock;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message, buffer[BUFFER];

    SSL_library_init();

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    SSL_load_error_strings();

    SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    const char *hostname = "www.baidu.com";
    if ((host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No such host\n");
        return 0;
    }   
    
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    server.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr_list[0]);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(443);
 
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection Failed\n");
        return 0;
    }

    SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    if (ssl == NULL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    SSL_set_fd (ssl, sock); 

    long ssl_certificate_verify = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
    
    if (ssl_certificate_verify == X509_V_OK) {
        fprintf(stdout,"ssl_certificate_verify success\n");
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not connect to server\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (SSL_connect(ssl) != 1) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(1);
    }       

    char *request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                          "Host: www.baidu.com\r\n"
                          "Accept-Encoding: gzip\r\n"
                        // "accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n"
                        // "cache-control:max-age=0\r\n"
                        // "connection:keep-alive\r\n"
                        // "if-modified-since:Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT\r\n"
                        // "if-none-match:'3147526947'\r\n"
                        // "upgrade-insecure-requests:1\r\n"
                           "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\r\n"
                          "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    SSL_write(ssl, request, strlen(request));
    
    int bytes;
    int response_len=0;
    char response_data[500000]={0};

    while ((bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
            memcpy(response_data+response_len,buffer,bytes);
            response_len += bytes;

    }

    size_t index;
    for(int i=3;i<response_len;i++){
        if(response_data[i-3] == '\r' && response_data[i-2] == '\n' && response_data[i-1] == '\r' && response_data[i] == '\n'){
            index=i;
            break;
        }
    }

    char response_head[2000]={0};
    memcpy(response_head,response_data,index);

    for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
        printf("%c" ,response_head[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    uLong output_length_compress =response_len-index;

    char *output_compress=(char*)malloc(output_length_compress);
    memset(output_compress,0,output_length_compress);
    memcpy(output_compress,response_data+index+1,output_length_compress-1);

    for(int i=0;i<output_length_compress-1;i++){
        printf("%c" ,output_compress[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    uLong *input_length_decompress = (uLong*)malloc(sizeof(uLong));
    *input_length_decompress = output_length_compress*10;
    char* output_decompress = (char*)malloc(output_length_compress*10);

    
    if (decompress_string(output_compress,output_length_compress-1,output_decompress,input_length_decompress) == 0){
        printf("Compressed string: %s\n", output_decompress);
    }

    SSL_free(ssl);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}

The result of not configuring 'Accept Encoding: gzip' is normal

Well, for one thing, you are not checking if the response is actually compressed before you try to decompress it. Sending an Accept-Enccoding: gzip header in the request simply tells the server that you are willing to accept a compressed response. The server, not the client, decides whether the response will actually be compressed or not. So you need to check the response's Content-Encoding header to determine IF the response is compressed, and if so HOW it is compressed.
